# Sudden performance decrease in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, performance, insert, cache

I've got a problem with a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance. Last week the performance suddenly broke down. All inserts are very very slow. It takes 4-5 times longer than before. On the hardware we found no defects. We had the same problem a month ago, but after one week the problem disappeared as fast as it came.

I'm not an expert on these things but I noted that the performance on all databases on the instance is poor. CPU and Disks are not at their limits, so it shouldn't be a hardware performance issue.

I'll took a look at the cached pages count with this query:

```
select
       count(*)as cached_pages_count,
       obj.name as objectname,
       ind.name as indexname,
       obj.index_id as indexid
from sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors as bd
    inner join
    (
        select       object_id as objectid,
                           object_name(object_id) as name,
                           index_id,allocation_unit_id
        from sys.allocation_units as au
            inner join sys.partitions as p
                on au.container_id = p.hobt_id
                    and (au.type = 1 or au.type = 3)
        union all
        select       object_id as objectid,
                           object_name(object_id) as name,
                           index_id,allocation_unit_id
        from sys.allocation_units as au
            inner join sys.partitions as p
                on au.container_id = p.partition_id
                    and au.type = 2
    ) as obj
        on bd.allocation_unit_id = obj.allocation_unit_id
left outer join sys.indexes ind 
  on  obj.objectid = ind.object_id
 and  obj.index_id = ind.index_id
where bd.database_id = db_id()
  and bd.page_type in ('data_page', 'index_page')
group by obj.name, ind.name, obj.index_id
order by cached_pages_count desc
```

Here I found very high values, but I don't know if it's bad or not. The count is from 201.236 to 1 on the different tables an indexes. Could this be an issue of the poor performance?

Another thing I noted is a very high number of log writes while inserting data. With `SELECT INTO ...` it's much faster.

Can anyone give me a hint, or can tell me what this cached_pages_count exactly means?

edit:

I also mentioned high waititme during the inserts (up to 300.000 ms) Waittype is `CXPACKET` and wait ressource is `e_waitPortOpen` and `e_waitPipeNewRow`. The high values occur on `e_waitPortOpen`.

kind regards
Thomas

Comment: Have you checked index fragmentation and stats ?

Comment: Sudden perf changes may be the result of a query plan changing for the worse. I second Kin's suggestion of making sure stats are up-to-date.

Comment: How do I check the stats? They are switched to automatic update.

Comment: EXEC sp_updatestats is a fairly standard way to update stats. It is typically run after a large data load. You can manually check them with sys.stats or sys.stats_columns. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177623.aspx

Comment: Ok, I did all the updates on all db´s on the instance. But this didn't take any effect. Is there anything else I could check or do? regard
Thomas

Comment: I can't definitely say why your inserts are slow because there are too many variables -- especially if you've already updated your stats. I would check for blocking processes and deadlocks. Look at the plans for the inserts that are taking longer than normal to see if the plan is optimized poorly. Also, use the Activity Monitor to see which processes are causing the waits. You should be able to figure out if it's queries causing the waits or if it's the OS or the hardware. Have you tested your I/O subsystem's *latency*? Are you using distributed queries? Have you flushed your procedure cache?

Comment: PS - take care flushing the procedure cache on a production server. It could cause a fairly massive slow down of your system while all your queries recompile.

Comment: It seems that the high waittime always occur on "Parallelism (Repartition Streams)" Nodes in the execution Plans. What does that mean? How can I avoid this. In the Plan the nodes have 0% cost.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your statistics are getting out of date, then eventually SQL's auto update statistics will kick in and update the stats, proper execution plans are being generated, then everything starts running faster again.

If you have installed Service Pack 1 for SQL Server 2008 R2 then you can turn on Trace Flag 2371 which will change the algorithm which is used from the static 20%+500 to a changing value depending on the number of rows in the table.

If you don't have service pack 1 installed then I'd recommend setting up a job that runs UPDATE STATISTICS for all your tables weekly or nightly.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Is there a possibility that things will be more worse than before after updating the stats?

Comment: It's not that probable.

Answer (score 2):

We had a problem with AMD chipset where they would drop into power saving mode, reducing their clock speed by 50%.  Worth a look.